# What is difference between java.utill.Time and java.sql.time

Tags: java, time

I need some information about util package Time class and SQL package Time class.
Where we use util.Time and sql.Time

Comment: Do you mean `java.util.Time` vs `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: There is no java.util.Time